# Unique and constant ID from Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, unique

I'm looking for a unique ID associated with an Amazon EC2 instance.  This ID must not change across reboots/poweroff-on/etc, and the ID must not be able to be duplicated (by cloning the instance) etc.

Can someone confirm if the instance id (i-XXXXXX) is such a number?  If not, I suspect I could use the MAC address (if the instance has ENI option which makes MAC permanent).

Is there another number to use?

Comment: Voting to close, as this is extremely easy to [find](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vault-tool/nfd1LvFoiUY) [by](https://serverfault.com/questions/58401/is-the-amazon-ec2-instance-id-unique-forever) [yourself](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=319825).

Comment: I've been through the AWS documentation and it is not clear of the instance ID remains constant between power off's.

Comment: The id is unique as long as you have access to the resource. This includes shutdowns

Comment: I'm not sure what access to the resource means.  Under what conditions could the id change?

Answer (score 2):

### Your instance IDs are globally unique, for as long as you have access to the resource.

<sup>source: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=319825</sup>

---

By access, I mean so long as the instance is in your console / assigned to your account.

If you can't see the instance in your console, you can assume you no longer have access to that resource (and as such, can't expect you'll ever get *another* instance with the same ID).

If you see the instance in your console, regardless of state (other than terminated, which takes some minutes to be cleaned up from the console), the instance is "yours" and the unique ID will not change. This includes reboots.

If your instance needs to be "re-provisioned" or some other terminology in a notice from AWS, you can expect the instance will come up with a different unique ID. This sometimes happens if the underlying host that's servicing what you see as your "instance" needs maintenance work done that can not avoid a restart / tearing down of the instances that machine hosts, etc. Typically, this will not occur without ample notice from AWS.

Comment: can InstanceIds be then globally unique if I have multiple accounts for EC2 instances